# Java file download code design problem

Tags: java

I have a Java project which is used as a component in a webapp. This java code writes an xls file in a specific folder. I want to provide a download functionality for this file which should be triggered as soon as file writing is done.
The problem is - without a server environment, how can write a download functionality?

Comment: You need to clarify a bit what you're doing.  Are you saying you want to push the file to the user's browser such that a download window appears? Or are you talking about your component downloading the file?

Comment: Set up a local server environment

Comment: As soon as the file is written, the user should get a download window.

Comment: @munna: that isn't going to happen if the file is written to webserver's disk instead of to HTTP response. The user doesn't have access to the webserver's disk. Instead, all the user get is the HTTP response on the HTTP request s/he has sent. Do you understand how HTTP and servlets work? You cannot send files to client without that it has sent a HTTP request for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't write to file in a specific folder. Just write to the HTTP response body immediately. The downloading job should just be done in the webapp's code. I assume that you're using Servlets. If you set the HTTP response `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`, then the browser will pop a *Save as* dialogue. If you also set the `Content-Type` header, then the browser will understand what to do with it (e.g. it will then be able to ask *Do you want to open it in Excel or to save?* and so on).

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

// Now write xls to response.getOutputStream() instead of FileOutputStream.
```

If the API of that Java project is well designed, then you should have a method something like this:

```
public void writeXls(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    // Do your job to write xls to output. E.g. if you were using POI HSSF:
    // WritableWorkbook workBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(output);
    // ...
}
```

This way you can call it in the servlet as follows *after* setting the aforementioned headers:

```
yourClass.writeXls(response.getOutputStream());
```

Even more, it could easily be reused/tested in a plain vanilla Java application like follows:

```
yourClass.writeXls(new FileOutputStream("/path/to/foo.xls"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it. I show a download sql in my page.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; " +
    "filename=ContactPurge.sql");
response.setContentType("application/x-sql-data");
response.getWriter().write(procsql);
response.getWriter().write(sql);
response.flushBuffer();
```